# Convert Object in C# to JSON with Attributes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to convert an object like the one below:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public ListOfStuff[] item { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
}
```

To a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"listofstuff":[{
            "@stuffone":"1",
            "@stufftwo":"2",
            "@stuffthree":"3",
    }], 
"@name":"Bob",
"@surname":"The Builder"}
```

So that when it is converted to XML at a later stage the XML file is attribute centric rather than element centric. The part I am having difficulty with is @attributes I am using Newtonsoft.JSON for my Serialization, exmaple of how I serializing in C# is below:

```
string myJSONObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This isn't really about XML - it's just about trying to convert to a specific form of JSON. The *reason* for wanting those specific names may be because of XML, but knowledge of XML doesn't really affect the question, so I'll remove the `xml` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to specify the JSON name. Here's an example (ignoring `ListOfStuff` for simplicity - apply the same approach):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("@name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@surname")]
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = new MyObject { Name = "Bob", Surname = "The Builder" };
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"@name":"Bob","@surname":"The Builder"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, cant believe I didn't think of that.